# Export POD-structure from DLL

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dllexport

Consider the following source `library.cpp`

```
struct parameter {
    const char *path;
    int num;
    bool flag;
    /* and many, many more members... */
};

__declspec(dllexport) void func(const parameter &);
```

This compiles to the library `library.dll`.

As far as I understand, export declarations only export functions and data. Since the structure `parameter` doesn't define any functions it's not necessary here and I omitted it.

But

```
dumpbin.exe /EXPORTS library.dll
```

reveals, that there is in fact a real difference here: The method `operator = (const parameter &)` will be exported.

**Question:** Are there any important reasons to export `parameter`, i.e. to add `__declspec(dllexport)` in front of `parameter`? What is the best practice for POD-structures.

Comment: If I were you, I wouldn't export a structure outside the dll. I'd pass `path`,`num` and `flag` as "out" parameters of `func` as pointers.

Comment: Please keep in mind that this is a very stripped down version of the original structure. Think of it as if the structure contains 20 to 30 members. Of course otherwise I would prefer the parameter version too.

Comment: You could only see the compiler-generated assignment operators if you export the struct as well.  No, there is no point to that.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, POD like `struct`, which contain only data(that too of fundamental types) and no functions, are just declared in the ".h" file which is given along with the corresponding `.dll`.

```
//MyDLL.h -------------------------------------------------
#ifndef __MYDLL_DOT_H__
#define __MYDLL_DOT_H__

struct parameter 
{
    const char *path;
    int num;
    bool flag;
};

#ifdef __DLLEXPORT__
__declspec(dllexport) void func(const parameter &);
#else
__declspec(dllimport) void func(const parameter &);
#endif

#endif //#ifndef __MYDLL_DOT_H__
//MyDLL.h -------------------------------------------------


//Client_Of_MyDLL.cpp -------------------------------------
#include "MyDLL.h"

int main()
{
    parameter stParameters;
    //initialize parameters of stParameters
    func(stParameters); 
}
//Client_Of_MyDLL.cpp -------------------------------------
```

EDIT: Since POD contains purely data, so the declaration of such POD remains same in the `DLL` and the client of `DLL`. Here purely data means no `member functions` even if POD has another `struct` say, B inside it with some `member function B::func()`. So, are there no important reasons to export the structure along with the function.

Comment: I'm aware of this approach. My question is: Are there any important reasons to export the structure along with the function?